# Is it possible to install AMD GPU-PRO on Freya?

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers, amd, proprietary

I'm quite happy with my elementary installation, it even provides for some casual gaming fun. I just noticed that the next big driver thing on AMD's side is AMDGPU PRO

In theory this enables the GPU to use OpenCL, OpenGL 4.5 and some propietary AMD optimizations that are supposed to be pretty sweet. As far as I know my R9 270X is a AMDGPU card and should benefit from the improved driver.

I tried installing it, and since Elementary Freya is Ubuntu 14.04 it was pretty simple to get the installer to run. But after installing and rebooting Plank won't show up and it won't work.

Anyone has any experience with installing the driver, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

amdgpu-pro doesn't support your card

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/wiki/index/graphics#wiki_how_to_install_amdgpu-pro_hybrid_drivers

Comment: Wow, that's disappointing. They're dropping driver support for their higher-mid-range cards already?